# How can I make GeoServer's WMS layer .jar file in Android development Android studio

Tags: geoserver, wms, android

I'm new in Android development in geoserver's WMS map.

Can I get .jar file of GeoServer's WMS layer?

I couln't open it though I tried https://github.com/shalperin/android-wms.git

Comment: WMS is standard and GeoServer is just one server implementing it. What you need is nothing GeoServer specific but a generic WMS client for Android. I do not know if this works http://androidgps.blogspot.com/2008/09/simple-wms-client-for-android.html.

Answer (score 1):

You can download and compile all of GeoServer from github.com/geoserver or as a zip file from geoserver.org. However, it will probably not work on android machines as it (and the underlying GeoTools library) are not designed to work on android.

Comment: I run this before but I didn't get what I needed. I only want to get wms layer as my activity in my android app

Comment: what sort of WMS layer do you want?

Comment: http://mmcnav.com:8084/geoserver/wms?service=WMS&version=1.1.0&request=GetMap&layers=Tigri&styles=&bbox=77.2339248657227,28.5064010620117,77.2387619018555,28.514077&width=322&height=512&srs=EPSG:4326&format=application/openlayers

Comment: What is the solution ?

Comment: you need a WMS viewer - GeoServer is not the solution you are looking for

Comment: Can I get it through jar else tell me the way to get it and how can be done by WMS viewer ?